# What's wrong with tapply (args are unequal length) in this case?

Tags: r, tapply

Data was taken from there http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/b52664cf-bfd9-49ad-849a-cb88c92553b9 (English version)

```
 glacier <- read.csv("glacier.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
 str(glacier)
'data.frame':   518 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ref_Date  : int  1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 ...
 $ GEO       : chr  "Helm Glacier - southern Coast Mountains (Garibaldi Provincial Park), British Columbia" "Helm Glacier - southern Coast Mountains (Garibaldi Provincial Park), British Columbia" "Helm Glacier - southern Coast Mountains (Garibaldi Provincial Park), British Columbia" "Helm Glacier - southern Coast Mountains (Garibaldi Provincial Park), British Columbia" ...
 $ MEASURE   : chr  "Annual mass balance" "Annual mass balance" "Annual mass balance" "Annual mass balance" ...
 $ Vector    : chr  "v54326054" "v54326054" "v54326054" "v54326054" ...
 $ Coordinate: num  1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 ...
 $ Value     : chr  "-1460.0" "-780.0" "-2730.0" "-940.0" ...

tapply(X = as.numeric(glacier[glacier$MEASURE == "Annual mass balance", c("Value")]), 
                      INDEX = unique(glacier[ , 2]), FUN = median, na.rm = T)
```

gives error:
Error in tapply(as.numeric(glacier[glacier$MEASURE == "Annual mass balance",  : 
  аргументы должны иметь одинаковую длину
I've checked arguments and they seems quite normal for tapply function. Have no idea, what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
tapply(X = as.numeric(glacier[glacier$MEASURE == "Annual mass balance", c("Value")]), 
                      INDEX = glacier[ , 2], FUN = median, na.rm = T)
```

gives the same error

Comment: What does the Russian(?)  error message say?

Comment: `INDEX` is supposed to be the same length as `X` in `tapply`.  So try removing `unique`.

Comment: I've translated it in title "args are unequal length"

Comment: It's was first I've did, it gives same error

Comment: Thanks alot you give me idea what's going on. I wasn't subsetting index value. Make it answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to subset the glacier data frame and I would expect one or more elements in `glacier$Measure !="Annual mass balance"`.  Thus the column length of `glacier[glacier$MEASURE == "Annual mass balance", c("Value")]` is not equal to the length of: `glacier[ , 2]`.   If this true then you would need to subset the index also.

Here is a solution with creating a subset of your data to improve readability:

```
glacier <- read.csv("01530102-eng.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

glacierreduced<-glacier[glacier$MEASURE == "Annual mass balance",]
tapply(X = as.numeric(glacierreduced$Value),  INDEX = glacierreduced[ , 2],  
       FUN = median, na.rm = T)
```